# Trying to distill my sql query down so I get one table result

Tags: sql, oracle10g

So I'm trying to do a query on 3 different tables. One is a `department` table, one is a `branch` table, and another is the `employee` table. I have 4 different branches, and 3 different departments and employees that can work in any of the departments at any of the branches. my query to find the branches that have more than 1 department with employees working at it.

I did the following query:

```
select b.name, d.dept_id, count(*)
from department d join employee e
on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
join branch b
on b.branch_id = e.assigned_branch_id
group by b.name, d.dept_id;
```

Which gives me the branch name, followed by the department and the number of employees working in the department in that branch. so I get repeating branch names that have multiple departments with employees working in the department at that location.

My question how can I only return the name of the branch or branches that have multiple departments with employees working in them?

Right now that query returns this:

```
Headquarters    1   5
Headquarters    2   1
So. NH Branch   1   3
Headquarters    3   3
Woburn Branch   1   3
Quincy Branch   1   3
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: the result list is branch, department, employees

Comment: is it sql server or oracle? Conflicting tags. What is your desired output from above, just Headquarters?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
select b.name 
from department d 
    join employee e on d.dept_id = e.dept_id 
    join branch b on b.branch_id = e.assigned_branch_id 
group by b.name
having count(distinct d.dept_id) > 1
```